# Convert Binary Data into Image -Silverlight or Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

We have purchase application where user will upload invoice documents. We are storing documents in database with mime type. The document type will vary from user to user such as .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, image, .pdf etc … .
Customer requested that application need to display all invoice documents in PDF. Attached Sample Document..
Below are different sections needs to create on fly
1.      User details in header.
2.      Invoice name in footer.
3.      Invoice Summary Details in Table.
4.      Followed documents by invoice.
We are using Silverlight 4.0 with Telerik controls. 
I was thinking convert document into image and place in PDF. It looks very simple but when I started exploring those converting different documents types into image is not easy job.
Totally I am running out of ideas.
Could you please guide me in right direction how I can implement the above scenario?
Truly appreciate all your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From long explanation this is what I understood you're after:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray();
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
 Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
 return returnImage;
}
```

Hope this is of help, if not, please speak up